# How to catch full invoke text from powershell class in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, output, runspace

I want to catch the output exactly as I get it when I run commands in PowerShell.

For instance when I type LS, I get:

[image]

Yet when I use this code:

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(); // Create a new PowerShell instance
        ps.Runspace = runspace; // Add the instance to the runspace
        ps.Commands.AddScript("ls"); // Add a script

        Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();

        runspace.Close();


        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        }
```

I get the following output:

```
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll
System.Management.Automation.dll
System.Management.Automation.xml
WpfApp1.exe
WpfApp1.exe.config
WpfApp1.pdb
```

Although this output may come in handy, with an other application I dont get the right output in return, so I would prefer the exact output as I see it in PowerShell itself.

Is there a way to read the output as I get it in PowerShell, line for line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the exact text that powershell produces you then you can use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7) in the powershell command:

```
ps.Commands.AddScript("ls | Out-String");
```

[image]

---

You can also read the values by accessing the `Properties` of the `PSObject`:

```
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
    var name = obj.Properties["Name"]?.Value.ToString()
    var mode = obj.Properties["Mode"]?.Value.ToString();
    var length = obj.Properties["Length"]?.Value.ToString();
    var lastMod = (DateTime?)obj.Properties["LastWriteTime"]?.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", mode, lastMod, length, name));
}
```

<sub>**Note**, as mentioned in [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60796328/9665021)'s answer, you don't need to use `Runspace` to execute this powershell.  Consider using `Get-ChildItem` rather than `ls`.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, with the command `ls` it works, yet when i want the result of selenium-side-runner.exe i don't get the full text that powershell normally shows...

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note: This answer also recommends what part of [haldo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60794140/45375) shows, in a more focused manner and with supplementary information.</sup>

Modify your script to pipe your command to the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)
cmdlet, which uses PowerShell's formatting system to render to a string, the same way that output renders to the console.

```
ps.AddScript("ls | Out-String"); // Add a script
```

Note:

- *Windows PowerShell* assumes a fixed line width of `120` characters and with (implied) *tabular* (`Format-Table`) or *wide* (`Format-Wide`) formatting, *truncates lines that are longer* (except if the output object is of type `[string]`), with the point of truncation indicated with `...`
- *PowerShell [Core] 7+* exhibits the same behavior fundamentally, but only uses default width `120` as a *fallback*: when the hosting (console-subsystem) executable is *running in a console (terminal)*, the *console window's width* is used instead, which is the same behavior you get in a regular PowerShell console window (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629089/45375)).

To fix that, **pass a large-enough line width to `-Width`**; e.g.:

```
ps.AddScript("ls | Out-String -Width 200");
```

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, do *not* use `-Width ([int]::MaxValue-1)`, because every line is then *padded to that width*, which will result in excessively large output.
- *PowerShell [Core] 7+*, this padding is no longer performed, and you can safely use
  `-Width ([int]::MaxValue-1)`

A few asides:

- For robustness, I suggest avoiding the use of aliases (such as `ls` for `Get-ChildItem`) in scripts and compiled code.
  In the case at hand, `ls` wouldn't work on Unix-like platforms, because the alias isn't defined there, so as not to conflict with the platform-native `ls` utility.
- It's best to wrap `PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();` in a `using` block to ensure that the PowerShell instance is disposed of: `using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()) { ... }`
- There is generally no need to create a runspace explicitly - `PowerShell.Create()` will create one for you.
- The [`System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) instance returned by `PowerShell.Create()` directly exposes methods such as `.AddScript()` - no need to use the `.Commands` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can get compressed json output from powershell with this command

```
ls | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Then deserialize. Also this command provide extra info than see in powershell output.

Comment: Please note the OP's requirement: "I would prefer the exact output as I see it in PowerShell itself."