# Why is all the Powershell output not written to txt file

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script that I am running in Powershell Core:

```
 PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.pbix | 
Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime | 
Select-object -Property Name, FullName, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime -Last 10 
>> files.txt
```

Opening the file files.txt there are no columns for LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime - why is this and how do I amend the script so they are included in the text file?

Comment: I'd recommend to use CSV files for structured data instead of plain text. Take a look at the cmdlet `Export-Csv`.

Comment: `Out-File` is limited to the amount of space you have on your screen, if your screen does not fit, it will not show all of the data, try storing the output to a variable like `$test = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.pbix | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime | Select-object -Property Name, FullName, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime -Last 10`, then you can access any of the data with `$test.LastWriteTime` for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two asides:

- `>>` is a (virtual) alias for `Out-File -Append`; if the intent is not to *append* (to a preexisting file) but to only capture the current command's (entire) output, use just `>` / `Out-File` *without* `-Append`.
- `Out-File` and therefore also `>` / `>>` capture the *for-display* representation of the input objects in a file, which is *not* suitable for subsequent *programmatic processing*. For the latter, use a cmdlet that produces structured output, such as [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv).

That said, it's reasonable to expect `Out-File` to capture *all* for-display data, given that a *file* rather than the display is the target.

Regrettably, as of PowerShell [Core] v7.0, `Out-File` / `>` / `>>` are (still) sensitive to the console (terminal) window's width and capture only as much as would *currently fit on the screen*.

You can use [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File) with the `-Width` parameter to work around that:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter *.pbix |
  Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime |
    Select-object -Property Name, FullName, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime -Last 10 |
      Out-File -Width ([int]::MaxValue-1) files.txt # Add -Append, if needed.
```

<sup>Note: As of v7.0, `[int]::MaxValue-1` is seemingly the highest value accepted; `[int]::MaxValue` is *quietly ignored*. Also, **be sure not to use such a high value in *Windows PowerShell***, where each output line is unconditionally right-space-padded to that length, which would result in excessively large files.</sup>